# Invalid parameters error while using post service using key value pair in android

Tags: android

I am using key value pair in my post service. I am getting response as 'Invalid parameters'. I tried the same thing over post man using content type as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and it is working fine and getting respose as expected. Am i missing anything?Below is the code I am using

```
 private String invokeWebservice() {
    String data = null;
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        String webservice = Constants.BASE_URL + serviceName;

        URL url = new URL(webservice);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        if (isPost) {
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            if (jsonObject != null)
                writer.write(jsonObject.toString());
            else {
                writer.write(getPostDataString(keyValue));
            }
            writer.close();
        }

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = in.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(l + nl);
        in.close();

        data = sb.toString();

        return data;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("test", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

And I am using below code for adding parameters to the URL

```
private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (postData.length() != 0)
            postData.append('&');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        postData.append('=');
        postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
    }
    return postData.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you Are not adding parameter in request please use this approach.

create a JsonParser class . Name it

**JSONPARSER.java**

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Created by Ghanshyam on 9/18/2014.
 */
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    // variable to hold context
    private Context context;
    // constructor
    public JSONParser(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }


    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,String method,String params) {

       // boolean isReachable =Config.isURLReachable(context);
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            String retSrc="";
            char current = '0';

                URL url1 = new URL(url);
                // check for request method
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            if (method == "POST") {
                // request method is POST
               urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(params.getBytes().length);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                out.print(params);
                out.close();
            }
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                byte[] bytes = new byte[10000];
                StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
                int numRead = 0;
                while ((numRead = in.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                    x.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
                }
                retSrc=x.toString();



            jObj = new JSONObject(retSrc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Connectivity issue. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return null;
        }finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

now in your MainActivity make a server request in doInBackground method

```
     private class Sample extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            String status;
            String param;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }
      @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
 String webservice = Constants.BASE_URL + serviceName;

                    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(MainActivity.this);
                    try {
                         param="hash=" + URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+
                        "&key="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(webservice ,"POST",param);
                    if(jsonObject != null){
                        //code to get data
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);

                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: please use it and let me inform if it not work @Abdul Waheed